# Reinstall original OS without rooting (Oneplus One, CM11S)

Tags: cyanogenmod, rom-flashing, oneplus-one

I've a Oneplus One running the original OS that came with it (CM11S). Accidentally replied 'Yes' to  a google security prompt which identified the Settings app as harmful, and it was deleted.

As far as I can determine the only way of retrieving it is to reflash the ROM with the original OS, which I've downloaded a copy of. I've backed up most of the stuff on the phone, but if possible I'd still rather not go through the entire process of rooting it/unlocking the bootloader, etc. I haven't done it before and I'd rather not go through the hassle of wiping the phone and restoring everything afterwards.

If I understand the process properly, the point of unlocking the bootloader is to allow custom ROMs to be flashed onto the phone. I'm wondering if I can bypass this step if I'm only interested in re-flashing the original ROM. (Although I've a feeling that might still end up being seen as a security risk so not possible)

Or if there's any other way of getting the Settings app back, I'd appreciate suggestions

Comment: If it's the stock ROM, no rooting/unlocking is needed. You should be able just to install it as "update" via the recovery (if the device ships with CM, it most likely has a recovery allowing that) or by using [tag:fastboot].

Answer (score 0):

You can use adb and sideload the zip of the OS from OnePlus using the stock recovery. [Here](https://forums.oneplus.net/threads/oxygenos-2-1-4-for-the-oneplus-one.425544/) is a link to discussion with some tools to help you flash the stock rom easily.